# jsoup not scraping all elements?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

## jsoup

When scraping data from website that has 200 elements , the Output is only the first 49 or 50 elements of the 200 elements , why ?
 - how can i solve this prob. to get all 200 elements data ?``

```
Document d = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xsilver.TRS0&_nkw=silver&_sacat=0").timeout(6000).get();
Elements ele = d.select("div#ResultSetItems");

for (Element element : ele.select("li.shic")) {
    String img_url = element.select("li").attr("listingid");
    System.out.println(img_url);
}
```

Comment: some websites are using javascript to generate some page content. Jsoup does not run javascripts. You can try to use Selenium to fetch the page. Selenium will automatically run the javascripts. After that, you can use it's output by Jsoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other elements are fetched on demand by Javascript as is common these days, so they're invisible to JSoup. There is no way to have JSoup perform those fetches, so you're going to have to come up with a better way than scraping to get that data. I suggest you look at [API options that EBay offers](https://go.developer.ebay.com/).

Comment: i did it , but without using jsoup but with long code , loading website html and matching line by line with key then get data , but it's take long time ..
is there are an  legal way by Ebay ?? what do u mean by ebay API option that offers ?? (sorry iam senior)

Comment: I mean the way eBay expects [developers to use eBay](https://go.developer.ebay.com/). It's even free!

Comment: iam sorry , but i don't know how can i use ebay API ?
- can ebay API help me in scraping or getting data from it's pages and products ?

Comment: It's an alternative to scraping, which as you've found out doesn't work in your case. If you don't know how to use it, then I suppose you'll have to learn it?

Comment: can you send me the tut that serve me in my prob

Comment: I don't have any tutorials.